# Visual Studio 2013 header include failed

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, header-files

Does anyone know, why I cannot include my header files, although they are in the same folder? I'm just using `#include < inout.h >` in this example. The environment is Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
Also sorry for the german, but I think it's still comprehensible. Thanks for the help.
[failing header include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr2ig.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing inclusion to `#include "inout.h"`?

Comment: No difference, it just says ""inout.h"": No such file or directory then.

Comment: Nvm, you meant without the brackets. Yeah it works now, didn't know that was a thing, sorry. And thanks for help!

Comment: Why don't you use VS 2017? 2013 is outdated.

Comment: Because our university wants us to do the project with the 2013 version.

Comment: I looked at the linked info.  The header `inout.h` is NOT in the same directory  so the statement in your source code should be: `#include "../Headerdatain/inout.h"  and the last item on the compile statement should be: `-I../Headerdatain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem is that `#include <inout.h>` would start searching in the system headers, whereas `#include "inout.h"` will first check your local directory before moving on the check the system paths.

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `#include <h-char-sequence>`
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the
>   specified sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the
>   replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header.
>   How the places are specified or the header identified is
>   implementation-defined.
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `#include "q-char-sequence"`
>
> causes the replacement of that
>   directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the
>   specified sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is
>   searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is
>   not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as
>   if it read
>
> `#include <h-char-sequence>`
>
> with the identical contained
>   sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.

It should be said though that this is compiler dependent, so this may not always be the case, but this is the reason for your error.

Comment: I do understand that your question was resolved, but I went ahead and answered it so that it does not appear to go unresolved, as well as for other peoples reference.